# filtering array of objects in react not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects like below:

```
0: {Id: 1, name: 'xyz', pqID: 10, pqType: null}
1: {Id: 2, name: 'abc', pqID: 15, pqType: null}
2: {Id: 3, name: 'wer', pqID: 16, pqType: null}
3: {Id: 4, name: 'uyt', pqID: 18, pqType: null}
4: {Id: 5, name: 'qwe', pqID: 22, pqType: null}
5: {Id: 6, name: 'ert', pqID: 25, pqType: null}
```

I want objects of `pqID` and 10 and 15. Below is what I am trying which is giving empty array:

```
const newUsers = arr.filter(
    (user) => user.pqID == 10 && user.pqID == 15
);

console.log(newUsers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try that, with full array function syntax:

```
const newUsers = arr.filter(
    (user) => {return [10, 15].includes(user.pqID)}
);
```

Or the minified version, without parentheses and curly brackets:

```
const newUsers = arr.filter(user => [10, 15].includes(user.pqID));
```

Comment: You're welcome. The advantage of using `[].includes()` is that you could add as many numbers you'd like to match. Using operators (`user.pqID == 10 || user.pqID == 15`) has the advantage of having different conditions to match, but is longer to write if you have multiple items to match.

Answer (score 1):

Note the `||` operator

```js
var arr = 
[{Id: 1, name: 'xyz', pqID: 10, pqType: null},
{Id: 2, name: 'abc', pqID: 15, pqType: null},
{Id: 3, name: 'wer', pqID: 16, pqType: null},
{Id: 4, name: 'uyt', pqID: 18, pqType: null},
{Id: 5, name: 'qwe', pqID: 22, pqType: null},
{Id: 6, name: 'ert', pqID: 25, pqType: null}]

 const newUsers = arr.filter(
      (user) =>
       user.pqID == 10 || user.pqID == 15 // note ||
     );

console.log(newUsers)
```